# SSRS Dataset parameters not working

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So below is an example of my issue without any data in.  I'm having an issue where by I've created a stored proc with an IF in so that a parameter dictates which data set I create in SSRS, however when I pass the parameter in SSRS I don't get the dataset I request.  My example script is as follows:

```
USE [InfoPortal]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Report_SSRSTest]  
    ( 
        @ReportType         VARCHAR(255)    = NULL
    ,   @Debug              VARCHAR(1)  = NULL
)
AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET FMTONLY OFF


CREATE TABLE #data1
(
number      INT
,text1      VARCHAR(100)
,text2      VARCHAR(300)
)

CREATE TABLE #data2
(
number      INT
,text3      VARCHAR(100)
,text4      VARCHAR(300)
)



IF @ReportType = 'Y'
    BEGIN

        SELECT
                number
            ,   text1
            ,   text2

        FROM #data1

    END
ELSE

    BEGIN

        SELECT
                number
            ,   text3
            ,   text4

        FROM #data2

    END

END
```

So when I go into Datasets > Add Dataset, I select a "Query type" of "Stored Procedure" and select the stored proc above.  I then go to parameters and in @ReportType I enter "Y" and @Debug I enter "N".  I click refresh fields and then ok.  But rather than passing "Y" into the stored proc it seems to be passing nothing because I get the ELSE part of the stored proc returned as available fields in my dataset.  When I try with @ReportType "N" and @Debug "N" I get the available fields I require but Im assuming that this is because its passing a NULL into @ReportType.

Is there something I am missing?

When I run the proc SSMS with the same parameters as above I get the datasets I require.  When I run the stored proc in Query Designer within SSRS it is also fine.

So why would my report be passing a NULL as a parameter to the stored proc even though i'm setting the parameter to a value in Dataset properties?

Comment: You mention `it seems to be passing nothing`, have you confirmed? Use `SQL Server Profiler` determine that this is correct.

Comment: thanks for the response @t_m.  Yes we have run profiler and it seems that a NULL is being passed in the parameter even though we set it in the Dataset Properties.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the Dataset Properties, it does not pass any value but it retrieves metadata from the stored procedure.

You need to change your stored procedure to return same columns.

Change table definition so #Data2 has the same column names as #Data1 ..

```
CREATE TABLE #data1
(
number      INT
,text1      VARCHAR(100)
,text2      VARCHAR(300)
)

CREATE TABLE #data2
(
number      INT
,text3      VARCHAR(100)
,text4      VARCHAR(300)
)

-- Modified to add data
INSERT INTO #data1 (number, text1, text2)
SELECT 1, 'text1', 'text2'

INSERT INTO #data2 (number, text3, text4)
SELECT 2, 'text3', 'text4'


IF @ReportType = 'Y'
BEGIN

    SELECT
            number
        ,   text1
        ,   text2
    FROM #data1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT
            number
        ,   text3 AS text1   -- **MODIFIED**
        ,   text4 AS text2   -- **MODIFIED**
    FROM #data2

END

END
```

If this is not what you want then you need to give additional information why you would want to return `text1, text2` from one dataset and `text3, text4` from another database based on a parameter.

Comment: thank you for the response @t_m.  This is not really how I understood it to work though.  Whats the point in having parameters in the Dataset Properties?  I would need to return text1, text2 in my data set and text3, text4 in another because they are totally different columns returning totally different fields.  In your answer I would have to change everything single column heading to have an IIF within it to change the column name depending on the parameter passed.  Seems a bit odd that.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood how SSRS and datasets work. On design the report gets the column meta data that it needs for you to design your report. You cannot use the columns without initial reference to column meta data. There is no way to get all the column meta data for designing your report in your current logic. So you either get to use `Text1, Text2` or `Text3, Text4` in the logic you have.

Comment: yeah but I wouldn't want all the columns.  Say I just wanted the dataset with the columns text1 and text2, you're saying that I can't pass a parameter for @ReportType to be "Y" in Dataset properties?  Because if I did it would only return the dataset which currently has text3 and text4 in the logic above.  That's where my current problem lies.

Comment: I have modified the answer. You can use @ReportType to retrieve the dataset you want but the returning column must be the same. Answer modified to use alias name to return the same column name whether @ReportType is `Y` or `N`. Why don't you give it a try.